# Extract Data as per String Values

Tags: r

I need help to extract data out of this string which is a ga custom dimension. I have 100000 rows and this is a test case and all data is same as this string.

Outcome

**a)** I want to only extract the value after word query which is 3 bhk tried grepl but it did not work

**b)** I want to break up values for all double quotes example filters , entity, search id ...... till traffic_sourcemedium and store the results of all in a different column

```
{"filters":{"entity":{"search_city_id":"0b71e081339939e6a43a"}},"error":{},"query":"3 bhk","response":{"totalCount":0,"statusCode":"2XX","version":"A","data":{"templates":[],"filters":{"apartment_type_id":"4"},"modelFilters":{"SORTORDER":{"start":0,"end":1,"text":""},"BHK":{"start":1,"end":3,"text":"3 bhk"}}}},"service":"buy","experiments":{"map_marker":"true","seed_ab_new":"true","search_count":"false","crfv2":"true","moonDragon":"true"},"device":{"device":"desktop","browser":"chrome"},"url":"in_buy_real_estate_vadodara","previous_url":"","time_stamp":1531982158065,"huid":"c27cb9db8bb0fa372122849134fcf90c","uid":"81332890","sid":6,"count":2859,"algo_profile":"user_profile","algo_type":"MC","traffic_sourcemedium":"google / organic"}
```

Comment: Is it [json file](https://json.org/example.html)? Maybe use R json packages?

Comment: this is a valid json formatted data, try something like `jsonlite::fromJSON(line)` will get what you want

Comment: This is a nested `json` file. since `query` is a main key, you can just do  `jsonlite::fromJSON(a)$query` or  `rjson::fromJSON(a)$query` or `RJSONIO::fromJSON(a)$query` where `a` is your data above

Comment: NO its a string extracted from google analytics report